Blender 4.2.3 python : display a list of object in outliner as "Search" does
I am trying to a do multiple field search in the outliner.
Simple exemple : searching object that are hidden in viewPort AND with camera visibility disabled.
Such search with python is very easy but how can i display the result.
Is it possible to interact with the "search" field of outliner using python?
( handling a search result in outliner is so convenient)
Or is it possible to have a list of object that I can manipulate easely in Blender?
( Like toggling different visibility aspects)
Thanks a lot

If the outliner is not filtered by text, you may consider add a temporary collection for custom search.

Adding objects to a temporary collection in Python was the first thing that came to my mind as well. Since objects can be in multiple collections that also does not have to mess up your regular collections you use for scene management and other things. I believe there is no way to manipulate search in Outliner directly from the Python API. You could probably modify the names as well, but that seems a lot less elegant and will probably have way more possible problems.

Thanks to both of you.. If an object can be in 2 different collection, that could be a nice way indeed. I'll check and write my breakthroughs

I found an super nice add-on called "Check Visibility". I think I 'll get inspire from it.
